# Where to Specify Java Script in a asp:content page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I had a html page where I was using java script to collapse and expand Gridview. However, I had to switch to a asp:content page(part of a master page) where I don't have head tag.

I tried specifying the java script inside the asp:content but it is not working.
Also, I tried specifying itmy master page still its not working.

How to deal with it any ideas?

Here is the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function collapseExpand(obj) {
    var gvObject = document.getElementById(obj);
    var imageID = document.getElementById('image' + obj);

    if (gvObject.style.display == "none") {
        gvObject.style.display = "inline";
        imageID.src = "~/ims/Images/bullet_toggle_minus.jpg";
    }
    else {
        gvObject.style.display = "none";
        imageID.src = "~/ims/Images/bullet_toggle_plus.jpg";
    }
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify script at any place in your page. As soon as browser sees script tag it executes script inside it.
But in this case I think you should execute your code inside `window.onload` event handler because you need to wait until you markup is loaded and then you need to call your function. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    function collapseExpand(obj) {
        var gvObject = document.getElementById(obj);
        var imageID = document.getElementById('image' + obj);

        if (gvObject.style.display == "none") {
            gvObject.style.display = "inline";
            imageID.src = "~/ims/Images/bullet_toggle_minus.jpg";
        }
        else {
            gvObject.style.display = "none";
            imageID.src = "~/ims/Images/bullet_toggle_plus.jpg";
        }
    }
    collapseExpand("yourOfYourElement");
}
     </script>
```

Or you can register calling your function after some event raises. For example:

```
document.onclick = function(){
    collapseExpand("yourOfYourElement");
}
```